# Using CStdioFile for writing string

Tags: c++, string, mfc, cfile

I want to write data stored in a vector into a file. Therefore I use the following routine:

```
bool Grid::saveToFile() {
    stringstream sstream;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < taglist.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i != 0)
            sstream << ",";
        sstream << taglist[i];
    }
    string s = sstream.str();

    CFileDialog FileDlg(FALSE);

    if (FileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK) {
        CString pathName = FileDlg.GetPathName();
        CStdioFile outputFile(pathName, CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeCreate);
        outputFile.WriteString((LPCTSTR)s.c_str());
        outputFile.Close();
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

The problem is: Although there's data in s, the output file is always NULL. Can anybody solve that mystery?

Comment: Try `outputFile.WriteString(CString(s.c_str()));` CString has built-in converters to/from Unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New MFC projects are created as Unicode, so I assume this is Unicode.

Also your use of `(LPCTSTR)` suggests you are getting an error and you try to fix by casting (it doesn't work)

You should create the file as Unicode, and use wide string `std::` functions such as `std::wstring` or `std::wstringstream`

Example:

```
CStdioFile f(L"test.txt", 
    CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeCreate | CFile::typeUnicode);

std::wstringstream ss;
ss << L"Test123\r\n";
ss << L"ελληνικά\r\n";

f.WriteString(ss.str().c_str());
```

Edit

By the way, you can also use `std::wofstream` with `pubsetbuf` to write directly to stream in Unicode

```
std::wofstream fout(L"test.txt", std::ios::binary);
wchar_t buf[128];
fout.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, 128);
fout << L"Test1234, ";
fout << L"ελληνικά, ";
```

And similarly use `std::wifstream` to open the stream

```
std::wifstream fin(L"test.txt", std::ios::binary);
wchar_t buf[128];
fin.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, 128);
```